# Spring Batch FlatFileItemWriter : getting "requested array size exceeds VM limit" when writing file with large number of columns

Tags: java, spring, string, out-of-memory, spring-batch

I am encountering the following exception while using a `FlatFileItemWriter` in Spring batch to write data from a `Map` (i.e a cache) to a file :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
        at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:300)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:344)
        at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:918)
        at org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.TransactionAwareBufferedWriter.getBufferSize(TransactionAwareBufferedWriter.java:163)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter$OutputState.position(FlatFileItemWriter.java:442)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.update(FlatFileItemWriter.java:366)
```

I took a look at the code present at line **163** in the `TransactionAwareBufferedWriter` class of Spring Batch which is as follows :

```
public long getBufferSize() {
        if (!transactionActive()) {
            return 0L;
        }
        try {
            //Exception is at the following line - Line number 163
            return getCurrentBuffer().toString().getBytes(encoding).length;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new WriteFailedException("Could not determine buffer size because of unsupported encoding: " + encoding, e);
        }
 }
```

To give more background, the file I am writing to has around **129 columns** to be written. I understand that this is a high number but reducing the number of columns is not an option. Also, a good number of records get written to the file (in millions) before this exception takes place.

Looking at the exception and the line of code causing it, it looks like the issue occurs when the number of bytes in the buffer exceeds that allowed by the VM (array size).

I have read quesitons/answers on this site but most of them talk about using a better data structure. Since this code is not in my control, I won't be able to apply this solution.

Any directions on how I can proceed for resolving this error would be helpful

Comment: Which JVM do you use? I know there is a bug in regards to this in Java 7u67 and Java 8u40: https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8029587, https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8059914